# List cakephp cache keys by prefix

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

Sometimes I need to write temporary keys using ids.

For example: `Cache::write('tsi_' . $tid, 1, '5m');`

Is there a way to retrieve all keys by prefix (looking for tsi_xxxx) ?

Using cakephp 2.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from CakePHP You can not do it. But possibility of getting keys from the cache may be realized in your cache engine( for memcahed it may be something like this Memcached::getAllKeys ()).

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a way, using file engine ... Maybe in a future version